# Discovery in SCOM

Tags: scom

We have SCOM 2007 R2.  I need to do 3 levels discovery.  First level is the seed discovery and I use local app class and the native registry module in SCOM.  For level 2 and 3 I need to use app component class and powershell because it is a custom app.  But as soon as I created the relationship between the level 2 and 3, the discovery for the level 3 broke and nothing came back.  Once I removed the relationship between the two, my discovery is successful, but just missing the path information (expected since I have none defined).

How can I define multi-layer discovery (> 2) using the local app and app component classes?

Answer (score 0):

Yean,

Of course, I can tell more, as soon as you give me the source code for your MP, but right now it looks like you are failing with filling the discovery data for the relationship between levels 2 and 3. I suppose that your L3 discovery is powershell-based so you must create DiscoveryData for your L3 class and for relation class as well. And you know what happens sometimes? Despite of the expectation that you have your L2 entity already discovered when it initiate the L3 discovery it may not happen. So, you are trying to create relation from the new L3 object to L2 object, which is not completely created in SCOM DB yet. So, relationship DiscoveryData becomes non-consistent (because SCOM can't find ID of the L2 object in DB) and it causes the whole L3 object discovery failure.
That is my assumption, based on my experience with SCOM 2007...I'm not sure if it's fixed in 2007 R2 SP1 (which is the most reliable 2007 version).
How to fix that? So, you may get rid of multi-layer discovery and discover both L2 and L3 objects in one datasource - it is also bring you better performance!

I hope it helps, good luck!

Roman.